# "Pardon" vs "Please can you repeat that"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, formality, politeness

In a client/business conference call , when you do not hear, what the speaker was saying or the message was unclear due to noise disturbance, what is the professional way to say it:-

1. Pardon
2. Could you please repeat that?

Comment: There is no single short phrase which is both clear and polite in all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You could say, [*Excuse/pardon me, would you mind repeating that?*](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=excuse+me%2C+would+you+mind+repeating%22&oq=excuse+me%2C+would+you+mind+repeating%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...2281.20670.0.21084.33.33.0.0.0.0.865.7007.0j3j18j0j3j0j1.25.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..8.19.5540...0j0i131j0i22i30j0i13i30j30i10.9g3AFPQl-e4#q=%22excuse+me%2C+would+you+mind+repeating%22)

Answer (score 0):

Simply saying, "Excuse me," or "Pardon me," can also be interpreted as an expression of incredulity. If I need the other party to speak more clearly, I usually say something like:

*"There's a big party going on here, would you mind repeating that - louder and slower?"*

This way the other person doesn't have to feel self-conscious about yelling/repeating themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Nancy Mitford famously thought 'pardon' was almost a swear word and betrayed hopelessly middle class origins! I would say: 'I'm sorry, could you repeat that?'